# Rapid7 scan has detected issue on static web app deployed on azure and created using ReactJs

Tags: reactjs, azure, security, azure-static-web-app, rapid7

Microsoft FrontPage Extensions installed and enabled can have their permissions misconfigured.
All issues has been given urls like below -
htttps://baseURLOfStaticApp/_vti_txt/,
htttps://baseURLOfStaticApp/vti_pvt/,
htttps://baseURLOfStaticApp/_vti_bin/,
htttps://baseURLOfStaticApp/_vti_log/

Also, rapid7 gives recommendation as - Ensure that the FrontPage Extensions are correctly configured with permissions set to protect private information and operations.

How to fix this issue?